# How can I reach Django admin model stackedinlines in html tags?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm using stackedinline for for creating subtopic for each cancer type, in admin everything works fine, i can add subtopic for each type of cancer directly from cancer type creat/edit page, but I cant figure out how to display subtopic related to "parent" type in html template.

P.S. I'm new in programming

```
my models.py

from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField


class CancerType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="static/assets/images/types")
    description = RichTextField(default="", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Տեսակ"
        verbose_name_plural = "Տեսակներ"


class SubTopic(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(CancerType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    topic = RichTextField(blank=False, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Ենթաբաժին"
        verbose_name_plural = "Ենթաբաժիններ"


admin.py

rom django.contrib import admin
from .models import CancerType, SubTopic

admin.site.register(SubTopic)


class SubTopicInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = SubTopic
    extra = 0


class CancerTypeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SubTopicInline]


admin.site.register(CancerType, CancerTypeAdmin)

views.py

from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import CancerType, SubTopic


class AllTypes(ListView):
    model = CancerType
    template_name = "types.html"


class SingleType(DetailView):
    model = CancerType
    template_name = "type.html"


class SubTopicAll(ListView):
    model = SubTopic
    template_name = "subtopics.html"


class SubTopicOne(DetailView):
    model = SubTopic
    template_name = "subtopic.html"


type.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<img src="{% url 'home' %}{{ cancertype.image }}">
<h4>{{ cancertype.name }}</h4>
<br>
{{ cancertype.description|safe }}
<br>
{% for subtopic in object_list  %}}
    {% if subtopic.type %}}

        {{ subtopic.title }}
        <hr>
        {{ subtopic.body }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}



{% endblock %}
```

and here's my DB tableset

Comment: Are you sure that the data is arriving correctly to the template? Do you see your subtopics if you just print {{ subtopic }} directly in the for loop (I mean before the "if")?

Comment: Hi! thanks for your reply, unfortunatly got nothing at all with tag {{ subtopic }} :( well that means that data is not arriving correctly, but how can I fix it? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In that case I think the problem is in your views

Comment: I'm very greatfull for your replies, I'v added views in the code, can u please take a look? thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the template you shared is `type.html` or `types.html`? And also it contains typos such as it should be `{% %}` not `{% %}}`.

Answer (score 0):

As Jonas mentioned i had problem with my data, arriving to html. Few minutes of research gave me the answear.
the for loop through the subtopics.object_set.all returns the subtopics of current cancer type. So the hmtl should be like:

```
{% for subtopic in object.subtopic_set.all  %}
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="nav-link link text-black display-4" id="{{subtopic.id}}">
                    <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse{{subtopic.id}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse{{subtopic.id}}">
                        {{ subtopic.title }}
                    </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="collapse{{subtopic.id}}" class="accordion-collapse collapse " aria-labelledby="heading{{subtopic.id}}" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                           <p class="nav-link link text-black display-4"> {{ subtopic.topic|safe }}</p>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
```